# how to set up lots of Cacti devices and graphs?

Tags: monitoring, cacti

I have many virtual machines that I would like to monitor with Cacti.

Is there a script so that I can easily create about 100 entries? I am tired of repeating the same mouse clicks over and over again for each single virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this link, where you can find examples of the scripts;
http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/scripts.html